# How to create a backup file when a pg_catalog table is corrupted?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I use postgresql 9.6.
I tried create a backup file with pg_dump: pg_dump -U postgres -O -f file.backup database

But I got the error:
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: could not read block 270 in file "base/16393/1249": Invalid argument

with this query:

```
select
    c.tableoid,
    c.oid,
    c.relname,
    (
    select
        pg_catalog.array_agg(acl
    order by
        row_n)
    from
        (
        select
            acl,
            row_n
        from
            pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(c.relacl, pg_catalog.acldefault(case when c.relkind = 'S' then 's' else 'r' end::"char", c.relowner))) with ordinality as perm(acl,
            row_n)
        where
            not exists (
            select
                1
            from
                pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs, pg_catalog.acldefault(case when c.relkind = 'S' then 's' else 'r' end::"char", c.relowner))) as init(init_acl)
            where
                acl = init_acl)) as foo) as relacl,
    (
    select
        pg_catalog.array_agg(acl
    order by
        row_n)
    from
        (
        select
            acl,
            row_n
        from
            pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs, pg_catalog.acldefault(case when c.relkind = 'S' then 's' else 'r' end::"char", c.relowner))) with ordinality as initp(acl,
            row_n)
        where
            not exists (
            select
                1
            from
                pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(c.relacl, pg_catalog.acldefault(case when c.relkind = 'S' then 's' else 'r' end::"char", c.relowner))) as permp(orig_acl)
            where
                acl = orig_acl)) as foo) as rrelacl,
    null as initrelacl,
    null as initrrelacl,
    c.relkind,
    c.relnamespace,
    (
    select
        rolname
    from
        pg_catalog.pg_roles
    where
        oid = c.relowner) as rolname,
    c.relchecks,
    c.relhastriggers,
    c.relhasindex,
    c.relhasrules,
    c.relhasoids,
    c.relrowsecurity,
    c.relforcerowsecurity,
    c.relfrozenxid,
    c.relminmxid,
    tc.oid as toid,
    tc.relfrozenxid as tfrozenxid,
    tc.relminmxid as tminmxid,
    c.relpersistence,
    c.relispopulated,
    c.relreplident,
    c.relpages,
    case
        when c.reloftype <> 0 then c.reloftype::pg_catalog.regtype
        else null
    end as reloftype,
    d.refobjid as owning_tab,
    d.refobjsubid as owning_col,
    (
    select
        spcname
    from
        pg_tablespace t
    where
        t.oid = c.reltablespace) as reltablespace,
    array_remove(array_remove(c.reloptions, 'check_option=local'), 'check_option=cascaded') as reloptions,
    case
        when 'check_option=local' = any (c.reloptions) then 'LOCAL'::text
        when 'check_option=cascaded' = any (c.reloptions) then 'CASCADED'::text
        else null
    end as checkoption,
    tc.reloptions as toast_reloptions,
    exists (
    select
        1
    from
        pg_attribute at
    left join pg_init_privs pip on
        (c.oid = pip.objoid
        and pip.classoid = 'pg_class'::regclass
        and pip.objsubid = at.attnum)
        where at.attrelid = c.oid
        and ((
        select
            pg_catalog.array_agg(acl
        order by
            row_n)
        from
            (
            select
                acl,
                row_n
            from
                pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(at.attacl, pg_catalog.acldefault('c', c.relowner))) with ordinality as perm(acl,
                row_n)
            where
                not exists (
                select
                    1
                from
                    pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs, pg_catalog.acldefault('c', c.relowner))) as init(init_acl)
                where
                    acl = init_acl)) as foo) is not null
        or (
        select
            pg_catalog.array_agg(acl
        order by
            row_n)
        from
            (
            select
                acl,
                row_n
            from
                pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs, pg_catalog.acldefault('c', c.relowner))) with ordinality as initp(acl,
                row_n)
            where
                not exists (
                select
                    1
                from
                    pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(at.attacl, pg_catalog.acldefault('c', c.relowner))) as permp(orig_acl)
                where
                    acl = orig_acl)) as foo) is not null
        or null is not null
        or null is not null))as changed_acl
from
    pg_class c
left join pg_depend d on
    (c.relkind = 'S'
    and d.classid = c.tableoid
    and d.objid = c.oid
    and d.objsubid = 0
    and d.refclassid = c.tableoid
    and d.deptype = 'a')
left join pg_class tc on
    (c.reltoastrelid = tc.oid)
left join pg_init_privs pip on
    (c.oid = pip.objoid
    and pip.classoid = 'pg_class'::regclass
    and pip.objsubid = 0)
where
    c.relkind in ('r', 'S', 'v', 'c', 'm', 'f')
order by
    c.oid;
```

I think some table is corrupted. Is there a way for me to create a backup without going through this query?

Comment: What is the query is supposed to do?

Comment: Catalog corruption? Restore your backup or hire an exoert.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver This query is shown next to the error. I understand that, when executing pg_dump, this query was executed in the process and corrupted data was read.

Comment: What happens if you use `psql` and run the query? What version of `pg_dump` are you using?

Comment: I get the same error: could not read block 270 in file "base/16393/1249".
pg_dump version is 9.6.13

Answer (score 1):

You have data corruption in your `pg_attribute` table. That table contains the column definitions for all database tables, indexes, composite types and so on.

Check if the size of `base/16393/1249` is more than 2220032 bytes (271 blocks).

You should restore your backup. If you don't have a backup, either hire a PostgreSQL expert, who may be able to extract information from the bad block, or cut your losses.